# How do I read a file into a matrix in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have a text file like this

```
A;green;3  
B;blue;2  
A;red;4  
C;red;2  
C;blue;3  
B;green;3
```

I have to write a script that if started with parameter `"B"` gives me the color of the row with the biggest number (from the rows starting with B). In this case it would be the last line, so the output would be `"green"`.

How do I separate the elements by `";"`-s and newlines and store them into a matrix so I can work with it? Do I even need to do that, or is there an easier solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`awk`** + **`sort`** solution:

```
awk -v param="B" -F';' '$1==param{ print $2; exit }' <(sort -t';' -k1,1 -k3nr file.txt)
```

The output:

```
green
```

---

Or in addition to @William Pursell's answer - to extract only *color* value:

```
awk -F';' '/^B/ && $3>m{ m=$3; c=$2 }END{ print c }' file.txt
green
```

---

Via *bash* script:

`get_max_color.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F';' -v p="$1" '$0~"^"p && $3>m{ m=$3; c=$2 }END{ print c }' "$2"
```

Usage:

```
bash get_max_color.sh B "file.txt"
green
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I want it to work for any parameter. For example if I start it with "C", it would search for the rows starting with C, selects the one with the biggest number value and then gives me the color of that row (which would be blue in this case)

Comment: @Aaron, look at my 1st approach, it has `-v param="B"` where `param` is a variable you can change to any wanted value

Comment: Yeah, I know I can change that, but again, if I change it to something else, the code would only work for that one parameter only. I want it so if I start it with "B" it gives me "green", if I start it with "C" it gives me "blue" and if I start it with "A" it gives me "red"

Comment: @Aaron, what does your **start it with** mean technically?

Comment: sh script B should give me "green" for example

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter out the appropriate lines and store the one with the max value seen.  The obvious solution is:

```
awk '/^B/ && $3 > m{s=$0} END { print s}' FS=\; input
```

To use a parameter, do

```
awk "/^$1/"' && $3 > m{s=$0} END { print s}' FS=\; input
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It does indeed gives the "green" output for parameter "B", but it doesn't seem to work for C and A. In case of "C", I'd expect it to output "blue" but it throws "green" instead for example

Comment: I get "blue": `$ foo() { awk "/^$1/"' && $3 > m{s=$0} END { print s}' FS=\; input; }
$ foo C
C;blue;3`

Answer (score 0):

A non-`awk` solution, possibly less elegant and slower than the already proposed solution:

```
sort -r -t\; -k1,1 -k3 file | uniq -w1 | grep "B" | cut -f2 -d\;
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

probably not understood what you want to achieve but

```
awk -v key="$c" -F\; 'm[$1]<$3{m[$1]=$3; c[$1]=$2} END{print c[key]}' file
```

will pick the highest coded color from the file for the key

some poor usage pattern

```
$ for c in A B C; 
  do        
    echo $c "->"  $(awk -v key="$c" -F\; 'm[$1]<$3 {m[$1]=$3; c[$1]=$2} 
                                          END      {print c[key]}' file); 
  done;

A -> red
B -> green
C -> blue
```

you can probably implement the rest of the script in `awk` and do this process once.

Or, perhaps you want an associative array, can be done as below:

```
$ declare -A colors; 
  while IFS=\; read k c _ ; 
  do 
     colors[$k]=$c; 
  done < <(sort -t\; -k1,1 -k3nr file | uniq -w1)

$ echo ${colors[A]}
red
```